# Is there a way to add my own button inside the edit common control?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, gdi

Say, if I have a default [EDIT common control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775456(v=vs.85).aspx) in my MFC-based dialog window:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to add a small "X" (or delete) button inside of it (here's my Photoshop rendering of what I need):

[image]

Is there a way to do it by modifying the default edit control?

Comment: Is that button at the right side really part of the mentioned _EDIT common control_? You may use owner drawing to achieve what you want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I was thinking of somehow using another common control, i.e. Button for that. The issue with owner drawing is... well, drawing everything by myself. That obviously involves visual styles and themes, etc. With an already defined button I could eliminate all that if I could somehow display it on top of the edit control, make Edit ctrl not draw where button is placed and limit the right-side edge of the Edit to right before the button.

Comment: [Insert buttons into an edit control](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/insert-buttons-edit-control) is basically, what you're looking for. In essence, you subclass a standard Edit control, and place a standard Button control in its non-client area. As long as you properly [subclass your control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm afraid such thing like a UserControl combined from other control elements, isn't available natively for MFC, unless you're using OLE, COM (ATL) or such techniques IIRC.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. It's not as simple as I thought, but sounds like it's doable.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider using new class `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl`. It does have method `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::EnableBrowseButton()` to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted more than one button, I would investigate alternatives:

- See the `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` class' code. Then decide if derive a class from it and extend; or else derive from CEdit, copy `CMFCEditBrowseCtrl` code and extend.
- Case the edit is multi-line, I would investigate the methods [CEdit::SetRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s492ze78.aspx) and [CEdit::SetRectNP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by73s9k2.aspx). Case it is single-line I would look to [CEdit::SetMargins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyc8t6cd.aspx). Then implement normal buttons over the text area of the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this article for CMFCEditBrowseCtrl class..

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35722/MFC-Feature-Pack-CMFCEditBrowseCtrl

Comment: The additional contribution this provides to the existing answers is the link and ...

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)